# Loading a Vb.net control inside a VB 6 form

Tags: vb.net, vb6, com-interop

I have a user control in vb.net application.

and i have a form in vb 6.

so in my vb.net applciation to this user control i need to mention the vb 6 form as its parent.

Means when i run a vb6 application i should see this user control as a part of that form.

Ahy help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [COM interop Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb419144.aspx).
It allows you to easily create com-visible .NET usercontrols, which can be used in VB6 for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try saving it as a dom object in .net
After this, you can open it in vb6 in the menu components.

I've done it with guid class of .net but i don´t know what you and to do, but i think you should try it.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually fairly easy to add some plumbing to a VB.NET User control to expose it via COM as an ActiveX control that can be used by VB6 and other COM clients.

Here is an article describing how to do that:
["Writing an ActiveX Control in VB.NET"](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dsandor/ActiveXInNet11102005040748AM/ActiveXInNet.aspx)